# How can I check for updates of a package/plugin directly form the terminal?

Tags: npm, terminal, yarnpkg, package-managers, npm-scripts

Assume I want to check if there is a new Yarn version to upgrade to (my question is not just for Yarn, it's just for the sake of having an example).

I know that I can do:
`yarn -v`
or `yarn --version` and then go on Yarn's website to see which is their most recent stable version, and compare with what was outputted in the terminal. But what if I wanna check if there is a new stable version that I might want to upgrade to without leaving the terminal? There must be a quick command in the terminal to check for updates, like `yarn --check-for-updates` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in the yarn docs: `yarn outdated`. Does exactly what I need and doesn't require installing an external package.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of npm packages which perform similar actions, but I've long used and recommend [`david`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/david). The output will look similar to:

[image]

Comment: Seems like I wrongly assumed there would be something more "built-in" for this. This package seems to do exactly what I needed, will give it a try, thanks!